# function overrides other function

Tags: javascript

I find myself doing a trivia. The beginning of this code contains two functions **`pedirNombre`** (is a function that asks for the users name) and **`triviaA`** , which is an eventListener of **`botonA`** (that is meant to be a button).

So far I've managed to get **`triviaA`** to not override the **`pedirNombre`** function with the **`done()`** method on line 56. However, it still runs pretty early.

Therefore, I want to know if I am using the method correctly. On the other hand, when pressing **`botonA`** and executing the function, the inspector returns that **`pregunta[i]`**  is not defined, and neither **`pregunta`**.

```js
//ELEMENTOS GLOBALES
let preguntas_respuestas = [
    {
        p: '¿Qué significa tomarse la pastilla roja?',
        r: ['Liberarse de la realidad virtual de matrix y dirigirse al mundo real', ' respuesta incorrecta ', ' respuesta incorrecta']
    },
    {
        p: '¿Cuál es el nombre real de Neo?',
        r: ['Thomas', 'respuesta incorrecta', 'respuesta incorrecta']            
    }, 
    {
        p: '¿Qué actriz interpretó a Trinity?',
        r: ['Carrie Anne Moss', 'respuesta incorrecta', 'respuesta incorrecta']            
    },
    {
        p: '¿Cómo se llama el aerodeslizador de transporte de Morfeo?',
        r:['Nebuchadnezzar', 'respuesta incrrecta', 'respuesta incorrecta']            
    }
]

let contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor')
let bienvenida = document.querySelector('.bienvenida')
let divBotones = document.createElement('div')
    divBotones.setAttribute('id', 'divBotones')
let botonA = document.createElement('button')
    botonA.innerText = 'Preguntas de tipo A'    
let botonB = document.createElement('button')
    botonB.innerText = 'Preguntas de tipo B'
    
let pedirNombre = (nombre) =>{
    nombre = prompt('Bienvenidx \n ¿Cuál es tu nombre?')
    let saludo = bienvenida
    if(nombre !== null ){
        bienvenida.innerText = `Hola ${nombre.toUpperCase()}, ¿listx para jugar?`
    } else {
        bienvenida.innerText = 'Hola Anonimx, ¿listx para jugar?'
    } 
    contenedor.appendChild(divBotones)
    divBotones.append(botonA, botonB)
    return saludo
}

pedirNombre()

//creando una funcion para las preguntas tipo A
let triviaA = (i) =>{
//tomando la pregunta del array de preguntas 
let pregunta = preguntas_respuestas[i]
//colocar la pregunta dentro del html
let p_html = `<h5>pregunta.p</h5>
bienvenida.innerText = p_html
}

//agregar event listener al boton A
botonA.addEventListener('click', triviaA)
//ejecutar funcion luego de que funcion pedirNombre termine
triviaA(0).done(pedirNombre)
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: #4d09cd;
    
}

#contenedor{
    width: 400px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: rgb(228, 233, 88);  
    border-radius: 1rem;
   box-shadow: 10px 10px black;
   padding: 5%;
   position: relative;
   top: 20rem;
   left: 20rem;
   overflow: auto;   
}

.bienvenida{
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    
}
.botonA, .botonB{
    padding: 0.5rem ;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background-color: #4d09cd;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#divBotones button{
    font-size: large;
    padding: 0.5rem ;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background-color: #4d09cd;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
}

.correcto{
    padding: .5rem;
    background-color: rgb(145, 218, 34);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
.incorrecto{
    padding: .5rem;
    background-color: rgb(188, 21, 21);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
.circulo{
    background-color: rgb(145, 218, 34);
    border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
    <main>
    <div id="contenedor">
      <h5 class="bienvenida"></h5>
        
        
        
    </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: You're doing `let pregunta = preguntas_respuestas[i]`, then `let p_html = pregunta[i]`. One array access is enough.

Comment: "*I've managed to get `triviaA` to not override the `pedirNombre` function with the `done()` method on line 56.*" - I have no idea what that means, but it's not related to the "*`pregunta[i]` is not defined*" error.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for the answer. It is not related, they are different topics.  I apologise for the use of my verbal conectors in case i havent been clear. I am not getting useful responses on the spanish version of this forum.  I would like to know if the method done() is used properly

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen that before. But no, you're not using it correctly, `triviaA(0)` does not return an object that has a `done` method.